# using md5 hash as audio link / src

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, audio, md5

The goal is to play an audio file using an md5 hash as the src. How can this be done?

```
<embed src ="cef83b993c716dd543b6fa4f053cc4a4" hidden="true" autostart="true"></embed>
```

*cef83b993c716dd543b6fa4f053cc4a4 = hashed version of 'control.mp3'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that If I rename file to the hash I can add .mp3 afterwords and play audio with Jquery / Javascript

```
<span class="play" src="cef83b993c716dd543b6fa4f053cc4a4">Play</span>


<script>
$(".play").on('click', function(){
var audio = new Audio($(this).attr('src') + ".mp3");
audio.play();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no practical way to convert a MD5 hash back to the original data which produced it - MD5 is not a compression algorithm. :)

Comment: What about retrieving the link that is associated with the MD5 from a database?

Comment: @Jeff The browser can't do that on its own. You could pass the MD5 hash to a server-side script that retrieves the appropriate sample, but you'd need to reference that in the `src`, not just the MD5 hash.